# How to properly cache DOM element in jquery?

Tags: jquery, list, dom

I am having some trouble accessing cached DOM element from the namespace variable. My FeedManager config variable is like this:

```
var FeedManager = {
    config : {
        $feedContainer : $('#feedContainer'),
        feedUrl : 'http://rss......',
        feedLimit : 10
    },....
```

Here the $feedContainer is the ul element in the html. I wanted to add li elements built from the feed. I have a funciton init() inside FeedManager object. But somehow it can not add the child element.

```
    init: function(){
          var feed = new google.feeds.Feed(FeedManager.config.feedUrl);
              ......
              ......
              // this is not working 
              FeedManager.config.$feedContainer.append(li);
```

but if inside init() function,I  again  get the feedContainer element ,it works !

```
 var feedContainer = $('#feedContainer');
 feedContainer.append(li);
```

What can be the problem? and how can I use cached dom element initialzied in my config object.

Comment: Could you not create the element in a document fragment, append the list elements and then inject into the DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to make sure the `$('#feedContainer')` has already been loaded.

An analogous example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
var Manager = {
    config: {
        $p: $("p#hello")
    },
    init: function() {
        var label = Manager.config.$p.html();
        console.log(label);
    }
};
Manager.init();
});
</script>
```

Comment: yes, when I run from the same html file it works, but when i use jquery from external js file using '
(function($){
 initWork = function(){
  FeedManager.init(); 
 };..... });', it does not work ! from dom ready I am calling initWork();

Comment: I verified the above script by separating it from the HTML. It still works properly.

Answer (score 1):

Is your #feedContainer element present in your HTML or is it fetched later? If it is fetched later than you can't cache the element, you'd have to use just a selector string like
    feedContainer: '#feedContainer'`

in your FeedManager object and then use something like

```
$(FeedManager.config.feedContainer).append(li);
```

If it is present in HTML then make sure that you define your FeedManager object after the DOM is ready, ie. inside of a

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // ...
});
```

or `$(function () { ... });`

Comment: yes, I am using the function once the DOM is ready and also the  #feedContainer is already present in the HTML. Still I haven't found out where did I go wrong. But if if cache the var using $('#id'), do I need to wrap that with $(..) agian or just var.append(..) ?

Comment: If you cache it using $('#id') then you only need var.append(...) but it has to be present in the DOM at the time of caching. Maybe it is added later to the document and is not present in the original html? You can try adding some test just before or just after the FeedManager definition to see if it is ready, for example you can add something like `$('#feedContainer').css({color: 'red'}).append('<p>TEST</p>');` and see if it works.

Comment: thanks,I resolved it,I called the init before the var initialized, it works !